# Not Able to get Connected with the Magento Store

Tags: java, android, soap, wsdl2java, magento

I have checked many alternatives before posting here..
I don't get why i am getting this Error like `UnKnownHost Exception`..Please someone guide me to the Solution.

**MyCalling Class**

```
public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
    private  static final String Method_Name="login";
    private static final String URL ="http://cws24/machinetest/api/?wsdl";

    TextView tv;
    Context mContext;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,Method_Name);
    request.addProperty("username", "android");
    request.addProperty("apiKey", "android");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopes = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelopes.dotNet = false;
    envelopes.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    mContext=AndroidLoginExampleActivity.this;
    try 
    {
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug =true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelopes);//Getting the Exception here
        SoapPrimitive resultString=(SoapPrimitive)envelopes.getResponse();
        tv.setText("Status "+resultString);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage(""+resultString).show();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage(""+e.toString()).show();
    }   
}
}
```

**Log output::**

```
07-17 02:20:43.376: WARN/System.err(25212): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: cws24:80
07-17 02:20:43.416: WARN/System.err(25212):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1037)
07-17 02:20:43.466: WARN/System.err(25212):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
07-17 02:20:43.486: WARN/System.err(25212):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145)
07-17 02:20:43.496: WARN/System.err(25212):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67)
07-17 02:20:43.496: WARN/System.err(25212):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821)
07-17 02:20:43.496: WARN/System.err(25212):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807)
07-17 02:20:43.496: WARN/System.err(25212):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:46)
07-17 02:20:43.506: WARN/System.err(25212):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:68)
07-17 02:20:43.506: WARN/System.err(25212):     at com.magento.example.AndroidLoginExampleActivity.onCreate(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:44)
07-17 02:20:43.506: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-17 02:20:43.506: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-17 02:20:43.516: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-17 02:20:43.516: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-17 02:20:43.516: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-17 02:20:43.546: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 02:20:43.546: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 02:20:43.556: WARN/System.err(25212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-17 02:20:43.556: WARN/System.err(25212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 02:20:43.567: WARN/System.err(25212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 02:20:43.567: WARN/System.err(25212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-17 02:20:43.576: WARN/System.err(25212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-17 02:20:43.576: WARN/System.err(25212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving to the Usage Of **XMLRPC API** from **SOAP API** has solved my problem.
Below is the code that I used  **XMLRPC**

You have to `DownLoad` the `XMLRPC` library for that.

[**Click here to DownLoad XMLRPC library for Android**](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/downloads/list)

```
package org.xmlrpc;

import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test extends Activity {


    String sessionId ="";
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context mContext;
    EditText username,apikey;
    Button login;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       mContext=Test.this;


       username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
       apikey=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.apikey);
       login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
   }
   public void checkUser(View v) 
   {
       if(username.getText().toString().equals("") || apikey.getText().toString().equals(""))
       {
           if(username.getText().toString().equals(""))
           {
               username.requestFocus();
           }
           else
           {
               apikey.requestFocus();
           }
           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please fill this empty field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       else
       {
           new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();   
       }
    }

   private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
       @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() 
          {
                pd=ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Please Wait...\nLoading data...", false);
          }
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void v) 
          {
              if(pd.isShowing())
                    {
                       pd.dismiss();
                    }
            if(sessionId.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "in Correct Details..Please try again", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Utils.sessionId=sessionId;
                startActivity(new Intent(mContext,Dashboard.class));
                finish();   
            }

          }


       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
       {
           XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient( "http://192.168.1.237/machinetest/index.php/api/xmlrpc");
           try 
           {
                   sessionId = (String)client.call( "login", username.getText().toString(),
                           apikey.getText().toString());
                   Log.d( "MY_XMLRPC_SUCCESS_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
           }
           catch (XMLRPCException e) 
           {
               Log.d( "APP_INFO ",  "Exception:  " + e.getMessage());
               Log.e( "APP_INFO ",  "Exception:  " + e.toString());
           }     
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I use same code but i get this code :  HTTP status code:404 !=200

Answer (score 0):

You should check the URL whether it is correct.

Comment: the URL when pasted in the browser gives the WSDL response so i hope it's correct

Comment: When I paste the link in my browser it return the error "The server at cws24 can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed". Is that service located on your local machine?

Comment: May be the issue is related to DNS hosts resolving. This is a good tutorial for configuring hosts in Android environment: http://www.sacoskun.com/2009/06/configure-hosts-file-in-android.html

Comment: Try with that hosts tutorial I provided above.